# Migrating the media files from one wordpress site to another

Tags: wordpress

I'm moving a wordpress site from one hosting provider to another. I copied the media files from the folder **wp_content/upload** from the source site to the destination. I see that the files are there in the **upload** folder.

I did an export of all the content from the source site. Then I imported into the destination one. This carried over categories etc...

When I go to the **media\library** menu item in the dashboard, I don't see all the files that I have moved. I see only half of the files that I have moved.

What should I do to see all the files that have been uploaded in the dashboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have the images inside the media library actual folder you could use the plugin ["Media from FTP"](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/media-from-ftp/) it will easily scan your actual media library folder and "add"  the images that are not there.

The plugin will "register"  the images in the folder to the wordpress database.

Another solution will be to modify your XML file to point to a place in your actual domain (the destination) outside the media library.

Say you have your destination domain as:  yournewsite.com

You will want to export the origin pictures to yournewsite.com

You edit the export XML file and modify all the references to youroldersite.com/wpcontent/uploads   to  yournewsite.com/uploads

You then move the actual images from youroldsite.com/wp-content/uploads/  into  yournewsite.com/uploads

That way you don't "overwrite'  the pictures when you do the import, you let wordpress read the images from your new domain and allow you to insert them into yournewsite.com/wp-content/uploads

For some reason, when wordpress tries to read the images from youroldsite it will fail and tell you media import error and you get an empty media library.

With the trick I told you, you will populate your library just fine.